# Feature extraction for ip addresses

Tags: pyspark

I am working on a machine learning project with pyspark. As a beginner, one thing I am puzzled with is that one of the input data is an ip address. My questions is how to use the ip address as a feature to train the model? Thanks!

Comment: No, I have not tried anything yet. I don't have any ideas of how to use them. Just try to get some general ideas here. Thanks.

Comment: What? What model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following for IPv4:
 - One hot encoding 
 - First Uni-, Bi-, and Trigram of IP address 
 - Difference between integer values of IP address 
 - Geolocation 
 - Euclidean Distance 
 - Hamming Distance 
 - Clustering

Here is an image i made with more details on each method:
[Ip address feature extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X10zP.png)